# Displaying human-readable text in perl Log::Report stack traces

Tags: perl, logging, trace

A library that I'm using [XML::Compile::Translate::Reader](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKOV/XML-Compile-1.23/lib/XML/Compile/Translate/Reader.pm) calls Log::Report's error method

```
      or error __x"data for element or block starting with `{tag}' missing at {path}"
           , tag => $label, path => $path, _class => 'misfit';
```

As I've got Log::Report set to debug mode, it returns a stack trace for an error.

```
[11 07 2014 22:17:39] [2804] error: data for element or block starting with `MSISDN' missing at {http://www.sigvalue.com/acc}TA
 at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/Compile/Translate/Reader.pm line 476
Log::Report::error("Log::Report::Message=HASH(0x2871cf8)") at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/Compile/Translate/Reader.pm line 476
<snip>
XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::LWPutil::lwp_run_request("HTTP::Request=HASH(0x2882858)", "CODE(0x231ba38)", "HTTP::Daemon::ClientConn::SSL=GLOB(0x231b9c0)", undef) at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/Compile/SOAP/Daemon/LWPutil.pm line 95
Any::Daemon::run("XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::AnyDaemon=HASH(0x7a3168)", "child_task", "CODE(0x2548128)", "max_childs", 36, "background", 1) at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/Compile/SOAP/Daemon/AnyDaemon.pm line 75
XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::AnyDaemon::_run("XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::AnyDaemon=HASH(0x7a3168)", "HASH(0x18dda00)") at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/Compile/SOAP/Daemon.pm line 99
(eval)("XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::AnyDaemon=HASH(0x7a3168)", "HASH(0x18dda00)") at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/Compile/SOAP/Daemon.pm line 94
XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::run("XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::AnyDaemon=HASH(0x7a3168)", "name", "rizserver.pl", "background", 1, "max_childs", 36, "socket", [7 more]) at ./rizserver.pl line 95
```

There is lots of juicy data in those HASH, SCALAR, GLOB, and other elements that I want to get logged; as we are having trouble logging the original request in case it doesn't match.
I've explored using

Some leads that I don't know how to use are using [Log::Dispatch](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2005/07/msg76535.html), or some sort of Filter on Log::Report; but in the end, all I really want is to apply Data::Dumper to those elements.